# Self Hosted Console app Being Accessed via JQuery Using JSONP For Cross Domain Access

Tags: jquery, wcf, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to build a Self hosted Service in Console application using .NET, which then needs to be accessed by a cloud hosted ASP.NET application (WebForm) using JQuery's Ajax call. Since it would be a scenario of cross domain, so I am using JSONP as data type for the call. I am getting a "parsererror" on the JQuery side, with this call.

Below is my Self hosted Service function code

```
Public Function SelfHostedFunc(userName as string, callback as string) as string
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://" & Environment.MachineName)

        Dim returnVal As String = ""
        Try
            Console.WriteLine("Rec  Request From Clinet...")
            returnVal = "Test Message"
        Catch ex As Exception
            returnVal = ex.Message
        Finally
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
            sb.Append(callback & "(")
            sb.Append(js.Serialize(returnVal))
            sb.Append(");")
            SelfHostedFunc = sb.ToString
        End Try
End Function
```

Console Main function code to create an endpoint

```
Sub Main()
        Dim baseAddress As String = "http://" & Environment.MachineName & ":8090/TestService"
        Dim oHost As New WebServiceHost(GetType(Service), New Uri(baseAddress))
        Dim ePoint As ServiceEndpoint = oHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(ServiceContract), New WebHttpBinding(), baseAddress & "")

        Dim behaviour As New WebHttpBehavior
        behaviour.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = True
        behaviour.HelpEnabled = True
        ePoint.Behaviors.Add(behaviour)

        oHost.Open()
        Console.WriteLine("Service is up and running")
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit ")
        Console.ReadLine()
        oHost.Close()
        oHost = Nothing
End Sub
```

JQuery Call for above hosted service.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {
                    userName: "testUser"
                },
                jsonpCallback: "someMethod",
                url: "http://192.168.168.168:8090/TestService/SelfHostedFunc?callback=?",
                                       success: function (data) {
                                           alert('success');
                                       },
                                       error: function (jqXHR, status, data) {
                        alert(status);
                       }
            });
        });
```

I am constantly getting a 'parseerror' with error message talking about  and no returned data. A lot of examples I have gone through with WCF services using web.config file based configuration but since I am creating my service end point at the runtime & also not using IIS, so I am sure I won't be able to use it.

Can anybody help or share any link which I can use as a reference point to help me out.

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: Is the error thrown in the callback of your jQuery code? What does the server sends back to the client? Perhapts it's a error 404 or similar.

Comment: Yes, it gets thrown on client side. On console application side, my execution happens fine, but then error handler for $.Ajax call gives me parsing error in status column where in jqXHR status code is 200 and statusText is 'success'.